# Blackjack program score total

Tags: java

So in my blackjack program when each game ends the program asks you if you would to play again. My main problem right now is that when the new game is started the score counter just keeps adding the new score to the old score instead of resetting to 0. Im not really sure how to fix it. Here are the two classes where the problem is.

Player class:

```
public class Player{
private String name;
private Card[] hand;  // from 2 - 5 cards allowed
private int cardCount,
            chips;    

public Player()
{
    hand = new Card[5];
    chips = 5;
    cardCount = 0;
}
public Player(String n){
    hand = new Card[5];
    name = n;
    chips = 5;
    cardCount = 0;
}
public void acceptACard(Card c){
    hand[cardCount] = new Card();
    hand[cardCount] = c;
    cardCount++;
}
public void showHand(int startCard)
{
    for (int i = startCard; i < cardCount; i++){
        System.out.print(hand[i] + "\t");  // displays one card from hand
    }
}

public int calcScore(){
 int cardScore =0;   
 int total = 0;
 boolean hasAce = false;
 for(int i=0; i < cardCount; i++){
     cardScore = hand[i].getValue();

 if (cardScore >=11 && cardScore <=13)
     cardScore = 10;
 else if (cardScore == 14){
     cardScore = 11;
     hasAce = true;

 }
 total += cardScore;}

 if (total > 21 && hasAce == true)
     total -= 10;

 return total;
}
public void incrementChips(){
   chips ++;
}
public void decrementChips(){
    chips --;
}
public int getChips(){

    return chips;
}
}
```

BlackJack class:

```
public class BlackJack {
private Player human,
               computer;
private Deck deck = new Deck();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public BlackJack(){
    human = new Player("");
    computer = new Player ("");

}

public void playGame()
{

    int cardTotal = 0;
    String answer, answer2;
    deck.shuffle();

    do{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        human.acceptACard(deck.dealACard());
        computer.acceptACard(deck.dealACard());
    }
    System.out.print(" Human hand: ");
    human.showHand(0);
    System.out.print("\n Computer hand: ");
    computer.showHand(1);

    System.out.println("\nThe computers total points: " + 
           computer.calcScore());
    System.out.println("Players total points: " + human.calcScore());

    if(human.calcScore() == 21 && computer.calcScore() < 21)
        System.out.println("You win");
    else if (computer.calcScore() == 21 && human.calcScore() < 21)
        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
    else if (computer.calcScore() == 21 && human.calcScore() == 21)    
        System.out.println("Tie!");    
    else if (human.calcScore() < 21)    
        do{
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to hit or stay? Type hit or" +
                " stay.");
            answer = scan.nextLine();

    if(answer.equals("hit"))         
    {
        dealHand();
        human.calcScore();
        computer.calcScore();
        cardTotal ++;
    }
        }while(cardTotal < 4 && answer.equals("hit"));

    determineWinner();
   System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Enter yes or no: ");
   answer = scan.nextLine();

  }while(answer.equals("yes"));
    reportGameStatus();
}
public void dealHand(){
   int i = 2; int j =2;
   human.acceptACard(deck.dealACard());
   System.out.println("New card: ");
   human.showHand(i++);

   while(computer.calcScore() < 17){
   computer.acceptACard(deck.dealACard());
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Computer's new card: ");
   computer.showHand(j++);
   }
  }

  public void determineWinner(){
   System.out.println("\nThe computers total points: " + 
           computer.calcScore());
   System.out.println("Players total points: " + human.calcScore());

   if (computer.calcScore() > human.calcScore() && computer.calcScore()<22){
       System.out.println("Computer wins!");
       computer.incrementChips();
       human.decrementChips();
   }
   else if (human.calcScore() > computer.calcScore() && human.calcScore()
           <22){
       System.out.println("You win!!");
           human.incrementChips();
           computer.decrementChips();
   }
   else if (human.calcScore() == computer.calcScore() )
       System.out.println("Tie!");
   else if (human.calcScore() > 21){
       System.out.println("You bust! The Computer wins!");
       computer.incrementChips();
       human.decrementChips();
   }
   else if (computer.calcScore() > 21){
       System.out.println("The Computer busts! You win!");
       computer.decrementChips();
       human.incrementChips();
   }    


 }

 public void reportGameStatus(){
   if(computer.getChips() > human.getChips())
       System.out.println("Overall winner is the computer!");
   else if(human.getChips() > computer.getChips())
       System.out.println("You are the overall winner!");

}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about setting the score to `0` when the game ends? Or create a new Object inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is your problem:

```
 if(answer.equals("hit"))         
{
    dealHand();
    human.calcScore();
    computer.calcScore();
    cardTotal ++;
}
```

Instead of making new Objects you use the old ones and keep their inner state. That means your construktor is not used a second time and therefore your score, hand, chips are not resetted.

How about trying this:

```
if(answer.equals("hit"))         
{
    dealHand();
    Player human = new Player();
    human.calcScore();
    Computer computer = new Coputer();
    computer.calcScore();
    cardTotal ++;
}
```

Also you have to make a new Deck everytime you start a new game:

```
Deck deck = new Deck();
```

**Edit:**
If you want to keep your `chipCount` place it in an `Object` wich will be initialiset in the constructor of your `Blackjack class`. After that call a function `chipcount.setChipcount(chips);` if you want to change the `chipCount`. Obvisoulsly your `chipcount-object` should have a getter `getChipcounts()` as well to get the actual `chipCount`.
It could look like this:

```
    public BlackJack(){
    human = new Player("");
    computer = new Player ("");
    ChipCount chipCount = new Chipcount(0);
}
```

here is how your object would be:

```
class ChipCount{

int chipCount;

  public ChipCount(int startChips){
  this.chipCount = startchips;
  }
  public void setChips(int chipsToAdd){
  this.chipCount = this.chipcount + chipsToAdd;
  }
  public int getChips(){
  return chipCount;
  }
}
```

Before youre asking. Of course you could make two objects (ChipCountPlayer & ChipCountComputer). Also there is the possibility of giving setChips & getChips another argument like:

```
    class ChipCount{

      int chipCountPlayer;
      int chipCountComp;

    public ChipCount(int startChips){
      this.chipCountPlayer = startchips;
      this.chipCountComp = startchips;
    }
    public void setChips(int chipsToAdd, String player){
      if(player.equals("player")){
        this.chipCountPlayer = this.chipcountPlayer + chipsToAdd;
        } else if (player.equals("computer")){
          this.chipCountComp = this.chipcountComp + chipsToAdd;  
          }
      }
      public int getChips(String player){
      if(player.equals("player")){
      return chipCountPlayer;
      } else if (player.equals("computer")){
        return chipCountcomp;
        }
      }
  }
```

that would be the other solution :P

PS: I am not fond of blackjack, does the computer even have chips? Anyway you could replace the comp with another player if you want to further extent your programm :D

Comment: Thanks creating the new objects did solve that problem, however it resets my chip count which I dont want it to do.

Comment: look at my edit :D and please mark my answere as aproved if youre pleased with it :)